# Save file to android memory

Tags: java, android

I'm experimenting with android, and I got to the point where I want to save something to internal memory and read from it, but I'm kind of stuck. I found this article http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and as it suggested I created dummy method :

```
public void test(){

    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();

}
```

Which always throws NullPointerException, anyone knows what I'm missing?Maybe some permission in Androidmanifest.xml ?

**QUESTION UPDATE:**

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Above line trows NPE. My class is abstract and its extending Activity, I don't know if that is relevant or not.

Stack trace :

```
01-29 22:30:44.575: ERROR/TEST(458): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 22:30:44.575: ERROR/TEST(458): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It seems that any IO operation throws NPE, I tried this as well :

```
try {
            File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
            String s = "";

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/Test.txt");
            fw.write("Hello World");
            fw.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myDir + "/Test.txt"));
            s = br.readLine();

            // Set TextView text here using tv.setText(s);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
```

Throws NPE, I even added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

into Androidmanifest.xml

I've made method and pass in Context ctx, but my ctx ends up null, how can I get this variable? set it to which value ?

Comment: Which line throws the NPE?  The call to .write() ? or somewhere else?

Comment: On what line does it throw the `NullPointerException`? In other words, what object is null?

Comment: @James House @CommonsWare I updated the question

Comment: Can you post the stack trace then?  The NPE must be happening within the call to openFileOutput() but it may be interesting to see exactly where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From extensive googling I found that you need to pass Context to your method, which you initialize in `onCreate` method `Context ctx = getApplicationContext();` and you pass it to the rest of the application which needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about the implicit 'this'. The Context-derived object on which you're calling the test method is probably null.

-- edit --

Either that or you're calling too early in your application's lifecycle. I believe you'll need to be fully initialised before you can call this - the earliest will probably be in your onCreate method.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying but I have onCreate method in my main class app. What must I do inside ?

Comment: @c0mrade - when do you call your test method? Activity derives from Context, so you can call openFileOutput directly, but you must wait for the Context to be fully initialised before you call it. Therefore the earliest you could call your test method in in onCreate. So you couldn't call in in your Activities constructor, for example.